# MongoDB Mongoose group by multiple fields and get the count

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've an analytics API written using MongoDB.

This is my sessions model

```
const sessionSchema = new Schema(
  {
    user: { id: Number, name: String, email: String },
  },
  { timestamps: true },
);
```

**I want to get the unique users count by the date.**

for the date 2019-10-24 there maybe 10 sessions from two users (id 1, id 2)
and

for the date 2019-10-25 there maybe 20 sessions from two users (id 3, id 8)

**So my expected results is**

2019-10-24 2 users

2019-10-25 2 users

I tried this

```
db.Session.aggregate([

      {
        $group: {
          _id: { user: '$user.id', day: { $dayOfYear: '$createdAt' } },
          count: { $sum: 1 },
        },
      },
    ])
```

and this doesn't seem to work.
My `createdAt` field's type is `Date` (eg:- createdAt: 2019-10-16T13:11:17.935Z) That is why I used `$dayOfYear: '$createdAt'`

Answer (score 3):

```
db.Session.aggregate([
{
       $project: {
          date: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$createdAt" } }

      }
  },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: "$date" ,
          count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
      }
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

At first group according to **createdAt**, as we want final result according to createdAt.

In this `$group` stage just push the **userIds into the array**, use **`$addToSet`** to keep it **unique**.

Then get the count of userIds with **`$size`** operator in  `$project` stage.

You get the result.

Here is the query.

(convert the date as you want, its just  a format, and you have done this, so I am skipping this task).

```
db.sessions.aggregate({$match:{}},
    {$group:{_id: "$createdAt",   userId : {$addToSet: "$user.id"}}},
    {$project:{_id: 1, noOfUsers:{$size:"$userId"}}}).pretty()
```

Hope this helps!